# Notification alert is shown only for the first message

Tags: android, notifications

I have the following method for showing notifications:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                _context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.menu_cartable,
                "you have a new message",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.sound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(_context, ActCartable.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(_context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(_context,
                "you have a new message",
                msg,
                intent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```

[image]
[image]

In Android 4.2 When a message is received for the first time (notification bar is cleared), a **big icon** (tickerText) is shown in notification bar and a few seconds later it is hidden and notification goes to notification bar. If I do not open that notification (notification bar is not cleared) and the second messaged is received, the **big icon** is not shown again but device makes the sound correctly and the content of the new message is updated successfully in notification bar if the user open the notification bar.

You should know that the **big icon** is shown all time in android 3.x.

How can I show that big icon in android 4.x each time a new message is received and notification bar is not cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can cancel old notification and display a new one with another id. It will  look like this:

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId++, notification);
```

**Update by @breceivemail:**

It works correctly if you put `++` before `notificationId` like this:

```
 mNotificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
 mNotificationManager.notify(++notificationId, notification);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you are right, when I tested it, I incremented notificationId in cancel.