# update notification tickerText

Tags: android

i created a notification inside my background service

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                .setTicker("text")
                .setContentTitle("text")
                .setContentText("text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pending)
                .setWhen(when)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(1000, notification);
        startForeground(1000, notification);
```

after doing stuff i want to update ***the tickerText , the contentTitle and the contentText of my existing notification***. Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can [cancel old notification and display new one][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18932684/341998

Comment: @Vang i can create a new notification with the same id as old?

Comment: Yes, you can and then it will be updated.

Comment: i have to write also  `startForeground(..) `?

Comment: It seems it's not necessary